# Use timer decorators to trigger telethon methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, telethon

I want to make a decorator for a project of mine that every x seconds certain telethon task will be started.

I've asked in the telethon group and someone give me a small decorator but the problem here is that I need to start the loop using `run_until_complete` and I already use it when starting the client. Here is my code:

```
def periodic(period):
    def scheduler(fcn):
        async def wrapper():

            while True:
                asyncio.ensure_future(fcn())
                await asyncio.sleep(period)

        return wrapper

    return scheduler

@periodic(2)
async def do_something():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Do some heavy calculation
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stingfy())
```

Now I already have a loop running in **main**:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

async def start():
    await client.start()
    await client.get_me()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start())
```

and I can't run another loop because if I do that it seems to close this one. Any ideas about how to make this work?

Comment: I don't see any attempt of calling `do_something()` in your code

Comment: I don't really know how to call it. Also do_something() is a async def(fixed it in the question) and I can't just use do_something() in main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you desire to run multiple functions at same time. So you can use `asyncio.Task` or `asyncio.create_task` to create tasks and add them into list, then run them through using `asyncio.wait` or [etc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

```
import asyncio

def periodic(period):
    def scheduler(fcn):
        async def wrapper():
            while 1:
                asyncio.ensure_future(fcn())
                await asyncio.sleep(period)
        return wrapper
    return scheduler

@periodic(2)
async def do_something():
    print("Im running")

async def client():
    while 1:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("This is client")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    async def start():
        task = [asyncio.Task(client()),
                asyncio.Task(do_something())]
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(task)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start())
```